# AWS XRay PutTraceSegments to OpenTelemetry Collector AWS XRay Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, open-telemetry, aws-xray, aws-sdk-go

Is it possible to send the trace segments to the OpenTelemetry Collector AWS XRay Endpoint? I tried to send some traces using the function `PutTraceSegments` and checked if there was an error, and there is none which is a good thing. But I'm not seeing the traces that I've sent.

The generated traces are from the service (e.g. Lambda, API gateway, etc.) so I wanted the traces to be pushed to the OTel Collector by using an AWS SDK.

The endpoint configuration is already configured for that inside the `LoadDefaultConfig`.

```golang
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx,
            config.WithRegion(region),
            config.WithRetryMaxAttempts(maxRetries),
            config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(customEndpoint),
            config.WithClientLogMode(aws.LogRequestWithBody|aws.LogResponseWithBody))
```

Custom Endpoint configuration:

```golang
customEndpoint := aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
    return aws.Endpoint{
        PartitionID:   "aws",
        SigningRegion: "region",
        Source:        aws.EndpointSourceCustom,
        URL:           "http://collector-endpoint:2000/",
    }, nil
})
```

Response Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{"UnprocessedTraceSegments":[]}
```

Opentelemetry Collector configuration:

```yaml
receivers:
  awsxray:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:2000
    transport: udp
exporters:
  awsxray:
    region: us-east-1
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [awsxray]
      exporters: [awsxray]
```

Comment: Are you sure the collector is receiving the trace spans? Also, I did not understand your use case of sending trace segments to Otel collector. The `awsxrayexporter` in the OTel collector can only process OTel spans and send them to X-Ray backend.
If you are generating X-Ray segments, then you can use X-Ray Daemon to send them to X-Ray backend.

Comment: The Central Collector and the app that has the agent collector is sitting in the same region. So the traces generated are from the services (e.g. API Gateway, Lambda, etc.) not from the agent collector. And I even try to send the traces to other regions using the `awsxray` receiver config, now it's receiving it. The issue now is that the exporter does not process it. The `awsxray` receiver only sends the traces to the `x` region. But I need the exporter to process the received traces from the `awsxray` receiver component.